# Conditional statement embedded in data-bind

Tags: knockout.js

I'm binding table rows using [`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) statement. The row HTML markup is:

```
<tr data-bind="css: 'new-row', rowClick: $parent.editCost">
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
<tr data-bind="css: 'new-row', if: $index() > 0 {rowClick: $parent.editCost} ">
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you can do it :

```
<tr data-bind="click: function(){ if($index() > 0) $parent.editCost($data);} ">
```

If rowClick is a cutom  binding, you can do that :

```
<!-- ko id : $index() == 0 -->
<tr data-bind="css: 'new-row'>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko id : $index() > 0 -->
<tr data-bind="css: 'new-row', rowClick: $parent.editCost">
<!-- /ko -->
```

I hope it helps.